# Errors in the app after migrating to ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I had an application written without ARC, now I added ARC and I do not open more some ViewController that worked very well. The error are: EXC_BAD_ACCESS, SIGBRT, ecc.
What can I do?

Comment: Can you give us some stack-traces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont need to use ARC on these view controllers you can always disable arc on them using the answer from this question [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)